# SQL error while running ALTER enum Rename VALUE 'A' to 'B'

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, postgresql

I am bit new to postgres sql DB. I have an issue where I have a Java Script file loadmigration.js , it basically connects to my instance of Postgres SQL DB and runs a bunch of SQL files from a local folder into the Postgres DB. I am running the JS file from command line in  local Linux instance using npm run loadmigration.js.
While running the loadmigration.js the script is ERRORING out at a particular  SQL which is  basically just altering a ENUM VALUE in the DB , below is the SQL its erroring at :

altervaluetype.sql (Contents below) :

ALTER TYPE test_status RENAME VALUE 'VALA' TO 'VALB';

ALTER TYPE test_status RENAME VALUE 'VALC' TO 'VALD';

ERROR is as below :

"msg":"syntax error at or near \"VALUE\"","stack":"error: syntax error at or near \"VALUE\"\n

Can some one help in understanding what is syntax Error in the above SQL.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: `rename value` first appeared in PG10.  What version are you on?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Mike I check this is my PG Version :PostgreSQL 9.6.16, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit